# How to consume Graphql Subscriptions in C# using GraphQL.Client

Tags: c#, .net, api, graphql, godot

"The backend is in nestjs and graphql using subscription-transport-ws protocol". I have used the code below but I'm not able to get any data or subscribe.

```
`var userJoinedRequest = new GraphQLRequest {
    Query = @"
    subscription {
        userJoined{
            displayName
            id
        }
    }"
};

IObservable<GraphQLResponse<UserJoinedSubscriptionResult>> subscriptionStream 
    = client.CreateSubscriptionStream<UserJoinedSubscriptionResult>(userJoinedRequest);

var subscription = subscriptionStream.Subscribe(response => 
    {
        GD.Print("user + response.Data.UserJoined.DisplayName + joined")
    }
);`
```

I'm trying to implement graphql subscriptions in godot using c#. I was able to get ad post data using mutations but I'm unable to subscribe for sse (server sent events). I am using GraphQL.client library (https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client), but I'm not able to connect / subscribe. Although I have connected it using Altair Client.

Comment: The latest version of GraphQL is version 4.  It looks like you link is using latest client code, but your server may not be at same version.  You are probably failing authentication.  There are more than one type authentication and most are moving from Windows Authentication to OAUTH 2.0.  See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/security/authentication/?force_isolation=true and https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration

Comment: Thanks, after upgrading, I was successfully connected and subscribed.